# Trying to pass a timestamp from a button to a label nested in a tableviewcell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Subject says it all, trying to get the time stamp from when the button is pressed to pass to a label nested in a tableviewCell here's what I have

```
@IBAction func updateButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Initiates Time Stamp for timeStampLabel in home view controller.
    let timestampVal = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let myTimeInterval = TimeInterval(timestampVal)
    let timeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(myTimeInterval))
    let timeStampString = stringFromDate(timeStamp as Date)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let restaurantTableCellView  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! RestaurantTableViewCell
    restaurantTableCellView.timeStamp = timeStampString

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(RestaurantTableViewCell, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Is your button placed in tableviewcell or in viewvontroller where your tableview is added?

Comment: tableView cell, in a tableView

Comment: That app is a view controller (or UITableview controller) that updates from one view controller and lists different restaurants based on distance, that is scrollable to show multiple restraunts

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to a wrong way.

1. If you want to pass an Object from previous view to next view. Yes,
   but the view you push to is ViewController, not TableCell
2. If you want to update a tableview, you should pass it to your datasource and then reload it

Comment: Would it be different if i had a view controller that had a tableview object, rather than a tableview controller?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to pass value in next screen and display in tableview cell then you can use below code

Pass your object in next viewcontroller like below

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let VC  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVC") as! YourViewController
VC.timeStamp = timeStampString
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

Use timeStamp value in your tableviewcell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? RestaurantTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.timeStamp = timeStamp
        return cell
    }
```